# Sub-query to count unread messages in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `messages` having following look

```
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+
| message_id | sent_from | sent_to | message | seen |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+
|            |           |         |         |      |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+
```

`message_id` is primary key

`sent_from` and `send_to` are integer fields having user id's

`message` is a text field

`seen` having "YES" or "NO" values.

I am using this query to filter last conversation of user having user_id `5`

```
SELECT a.message_id, a.sent_from, a.sent_to, a.message, a.seen, users.username, users.user_image
FROM messages a
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT sent_from, max(message_id) AS maxid from messages GROUP BY sent_from, sent_to) AS b ON
  a.message_id = b.maxid
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = a.sent_from
WHERE a.sent_to = 5
```

The above query selecting data like this

```
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------+------------+
| message_id | sent_from | sent_to | message | seen | username | user_image |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------+------------+
| 39         | 3         | 5       | hello   | YES  | ali786   | image1.jpg |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------+------------+
| 40         | 2         | 5       | hi      | YES  | john123  | image2.jpg |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------+------------+
| 48         | 1         | 5       | hello   | NO   | shahid7  | image3.jpg |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------+------------+
```

I want to add a sub-query in above query to add a column `unread_messages` at last. which will count the all messages from `messages` table having `seen` status "NO" sent by `sent_from` user id and `sent to`sent_to` user id

Comment: What does that new column actually look like for the sample data given above?

Comment: new column will appear after user_image and count the messages having seen value "NO"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize conditional aggregation using `COUNT(CASE WHEN ...)` in your inner subquery to get the count of unread messages as well:

```
SELECT a.message_id, a.sent_from, a.sent_to, a.message, a.seen, 
       users.username, users.user_image, 
       b.unread_messages 
FROM messages a
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT sent_from, 
          max(message_id) AS maxid,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN seen = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS unread_messages 
   FROM messages 
   GROUP BY sent_from, sent_to) AS b ON a.message_id = b.maxid
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = a.sent_from
WHERE a.sent_to = 5
```